# How to store image in Django - use link or no?

Tags: django, django-models

I have field:

```
image = models.ImageField(
        max_length=500,
        upload_to='images'
    )
```

and some settings to upload an image to AWS S3 Bucket, where `PublicMediaStorage` is my custom storage:

```
PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
AWS_S3_MEDIA_ENDPOINT_URL = env('AWS_S3_MEDIA_ENDPOINT_URL', None)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'new_project.storages.PublicMediaStorage'
```

I need to store and get my images from database(postgres).
For now my image stores at the database like
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWtwN.png).
And if i write `image.url` i will get the url of my image(that's why I don't need to store urls of images in my database).
But is it right way? Maybe it will be better to store immediately links at the database? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

OP is doing well using [`ImageField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) . OP might want to add `blank=True` so that OP's forms don't require the image.

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)
```

The reason to use `ImageField` is that it checks whether the image is valid and also uploads it to the right location, which is something one wouldn't get with a simple URL. That is why the docs mention it requires the [Pillow library](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

With regards to the DB path, [it is better to store the the relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/678293/7109869). OP can access the rest of the URL in the template if needed too and if the rest of the URL changes then OP only has to change in one place and not in the database(s).

Comment: Thanks. But can you say or explain: is it right way to store in the database path to image(not full link) and get image link using ```image.url```? Or i need to store full url?

Comment: @kstnk it's best to store the relative path. Check the last paragraph of the updated answer.